# Быстрая сортировка C++ (qsort)

Tags: c++, qsort

По ходу изучения предмета Алгоритмы и структуры данных, знакомлюсь с разными алгоритмами сортировки, конкретно с quick sort на данном этапе, задался задачей самостоятельно его реализовать, исходя из понимания прочитанной мной концепции, основными критериями описания функции были:

- Рекурсивное представление, посредством одной функции, параметрами которой являются указатель на начало массива и его размер.
- Логичность представления кода (сокращение по возможности), в отличии от рабочих вариантов, которые я нашел на других сайтах.
- Логичность представления кода (сокращение по возможности), в отличии от рабочих вариантов, которые я нашел на других сайтах.

Мой код:

```
template <typename T>
void quick_sort(T* unsorted, unsigned size)
{
    if (size < 2) return;
    unsigned left = 0;
    unsigned right = size - 1;
    T middle = unsorted[size >> 1];
    while (left != right)
        if (unsorted[left] > middle)
            while (left != right)
                if (unsorted[right] <= middle)
                {
                    T temp = unsorted[left];
                    unsorted[left] = unsorted[right];
                    unsorted[right] = temp;
                    break;
                }
                else right--;
        else left++;
    quick_sort(unsorted, left);
    quick_sort(unsorted + left, size - left);
}
```

Вот скрин результатов выполнения сортировки массива из 128 случайных значений:
[image: Консоль]

Проблема в том, что он исходя из всей логики все же сортируется по возрастанию, но дает осечку примерно через каждые 10 шагов, предполагаю, что либо из-за того что при разбиении на 2 функции пропускается шаг, либо из-за не учета при проверке равных опорному элементов.
  Надеюсь на вашу внимательность, если кто заметит утечку, либо подскажет, что следует изменить, жду ваших ответов..

Answer (score 4):

Рекурсивные вызовы для левой и правой части:

```
quick_sort(unsorted, left + 1);
quick_sort(unsorted + left, size - left);
```

Складываем ваши размеры левой и правой части:

```
left + 1 + size - left = size + 1
```

Нестыковочка получается! Почему вдруг суммарный размер получился больше исходного? Если не гарантируется уменьшение размера, то не гарантируется и завершение рекурсии.

И действительно, на входе `{ 1, 2, 3, 6 }` ваша реализация впадает в бесконечную рекурсию. Так что ваше "дает осечку примерно через каждые 10 шагов" - это вам просто повезло.

Comment: да, действительно, исправил эту неточность, но такая ошибка разбиения скорее обеспечивает только то ,что один лишний элемент сравнивается дважды разными функциями. все еще не могу обнаружить изьян в логике сравнения, есть соображения по этому поводу?

Comment: Если бы дело было только в "сравнивается дважды разными функциями", то это действительно не было бы серьезной проблемой. Но бесконечная рекурсия - это проблема.

Answer (score 0):

22 25 25 25 19 26

Результат надо проверять на нескольких исходных данных и проверять автоматически.
И в конце должно быть примерно:

```
quick_sort(unsorted, rootelpos);
quick_sort(unsorted+rootelpos+1, size - rootelpos - 1);
```

Comment: но ведь при таком разбиении выпадает один элемент посредине, на каждом шаге рекурсии, не понимаю в чем смысл.. получается что массив с arr[0] по arr[size-1] разбивается на arr[0] по arr[rootelpos-1] и arr[rootlepos + 1] по arr[size - 1], выпадает arr[rootlepos]

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0 в википедии так

Comment: там по другому немного, там сразу после завершения цикла указатель left = right + 1, а у меня left = right, хм, стоп, возможно к стати в этом и проблема, элемент по средине не сортируется, сейчас гляну..